# what is the minimal number of points which are not all simultaneously roots of any element in the span of multivariate polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, roots, matrix-rank

Let us have $N$ linear independent multivariate polynomials $p_j(x_1,..,x_m)$ of degree $K$. Consider now their span: since they are linearly independent, this will never be equal to constant $0$. What I am asking is: how many different points $\vec x_{\alpha}=(x_{\alpha,1},...,x_{\alpha,m})$ should we pick to have the guarantee that any (non-trivial) linear combination of the polynomials $p_j$ is not equal $0$ at least in one of these points?

My question comes from the following framework of a polynomial matrix, where each of its $R$ columns is given by the polynomials $p_j$ evaluated at the same point $\vec x_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha=1,...,R$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
 p_1(\vec x_{\alpha_1}) & p_1(\vec x_{\alpha_2}) & \dots & p_1(\vec x_{\alpha_R}) \\
p_2(\vec x_{\alpha_1}) & p_2(\vec x_{\alpha_2}) & \dots & p_2(\vec x_{\alpha_R}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
p_N(\vec x_{\alpha_1})&  p_N(\vec x_{\alpha_2}) & \dots & p_N(\vec x_{\alpha_R})
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I want the matrix to have full row rank, meaning that the span of the rows must not give $\vec 0$.
This indeed translates in having any linear combination of the polynomials not being $0$ in at least one $\vec x_{\alpha}$.

By knowing that the polynomials have at most degree $K$, is there a minimum number of points $\vec x_{\alpha}$ that can be freely chosen, which guarantees that the matrix has full row rank?

And bonus question: What if I can pick $\vec x_{\alpha}$, but only as vectors of positive integers?